# Checking for item in derived list

Tags: python

So the goal is to return "true" if the number 9 appears in the first 4 numbers of a list. I've done this by first creating a new list that contains only the first 4 numbers, and then checking if 9 appears there.

```
def array_front9(nums):
  lst = []
  lst.append(nums[:4])
  if 9 in lst:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

for some reason, it always returns False. This means that either a) numbers are not being transferred to the new list or b) none of the numbers are visible when searching through it. I tested the first one by printing the new list, but I don't have any clue why the numbers wouldn't be visible.
Please help!

Comment: After the append, lst looks like `[[nums[0], nums[1], ...]]`. Either just use `lst = nums[:4]`, or `lst.extend(nums[:4])`

Comment: print the value `lst` after the append.  this should tell you the problem.  you need to learn to debug your programs.

Comment: Am I being downvoted because this is a stupid question? I don't really understand why this is an inappropriate thing to ask

Comment: i downvoted this question because it shows no debugging effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are appending a list into a list, so `9` will not be in `lst`, as `9` is not a list.  You can greatly simplify your approach:

```
def array_front9(nums):
  return 9 in nums[:4]
```

Simple example showing what your current approach is doing:

```
In [1]: nums = [9,9,9,9]

In [2]: lst = []

In [3]: lst.append(nums)

In [4]: lst
Out[4]: [[9, 9, 9, 9]]

In [5]: 9 in lst
Out[5]: False
```

Answer (score 1):

You are appending a list into a list. You should try to assign the sliced list to another variable and use it.

Answer (score 1):

`nums[:4]` returns list, so you are appending list in list instead you can assign lst as `nums[:4]`:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    lst = nums[:4]
    if 9 in lst:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Even simpler way may be to:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    return 9 in nums[:4]
```